# Grab e-mail addresses from an HTML table

Tags: php, html

I have an HTML table that contains 500 e-mail addresses in this *file.html*.
Now I want to open it with PHP and get all e-mail addresses in it and add it to an array.
This means I have an HTML table and in this table 500 rows with an e-mail address in each row.

How can I get these e-mail addresses with PHP?

Comment: It would be helpful if you give us an example how your HTML table looks like.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree with The MYYN's approach but I suggest you use phps DOM class to iterate through all the td's of the table and fetch the emails.

Here are some useful functions:

[loadHTMLFile](http://www.php.net/manual/en/domdocument.loadhtmlfile.php)

and

[getElementsByTagName](http://www.php.net/manual/en/domelement.getelementsbytagname.php)

Answer (score 1):

You can parse the HTML via php to access the relevant pieces and store them in your data structure for further processing, a short introduction on PHP html parsing can be found here: http://www.onderstekop.nl/articles/114/

Answer (score 1):

I would avoid regexps for all the HTML/regexp issues and use an HTML parser such as [this one](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/). It should be trivial to extract the DOM for the table and contained cells/content.

Note that a regexp for identifying emails can potentially be quite complex, depending on the variety of the emails you wish to match. SO has numerous examples.

Answer (score 0):

You could use regex to match the entire HTML string with email occurrences.

http://www.regular-expressions.info/email.html

Comment: if you don't know how to google or use PHP's regex functionalty, you should probably read a bit more before doing more PHP stuff.

Comment: Regex is not the best option when it comes to html :( (it might work, but if you can use other methods, please do)